# How do I retrieve values from successive lines in perl?

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have this data below,called `data.txt`, I want to retrieve four columns from this data. First, I want to retrieve degradome category, then p-value, then the text before and after `Query:`. So the result should look like this(showing the first row only):

```
Degardome Category: 3  Degradome p-value: 0.0195958324320822   3' UGACGUUUCAGUUCCCAGUAU 5' Seq_3694_200
```

data.txt:

```
5' CCGGUAAGGUUAUGGGUCAUG 3' Transcript: Supercontig_2.8_1446328:1451-1471 Slice Site:1462
      |o||o||o| |||||||o
3' UGACGUUUCAGUUCCCAGUAU 5' Query: Seq_3694_200

SiteID: Supercontig_2.8_1446328:1462
MFE of perfect match: -36.10
MFE of this site: -23.60
MFEratio: 0.653739612188366
Allen et al. score: 7.5
Paired Regions (query5'-query3',transcript3'-transcript5')
    1-8,1471-1464
    10-18,1462-1454
Unpaired Regions (query5'-query3',transcript3'-transcript5')
    9-9,1463-1463   SIL: Symmetric internal loop
    19-21,1453-1451 UP3: Unpaired region at 3' of query

Degradome data file: /media/owner/newdrive/phasing/degradome/_degradome.20171210/bbduk_trimmed/merged_HV2.fasta_dd.txt
Degardome Category: 3
Degradome p-value: 0.0195958324320822
T-Plot file: T-plots-IGR/Seq_3694_200_Supercontig_2.8_1446328_1462_TPlot.pdf

Position    Reads   Category
1462    4   3   <<<<<<<<<<
2949    7   3
4179    517 0
---------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------

5' GGUGAGGAGGGGGGUUUG-GUC 3' Transcript: Supercontig_2.8_1511075:1311-1331 Slice Site:1323
    | |||||oo||| |||o |||
3' AC-CUCCUUUCCCGAAAUACAG 5' Query: Seq_2299_664

SiteID: Supercontig_2.8_1511075:1323
MFE of perfect match: -37.90
MFE of this site: -25.30
MFEratio: 0.66754617414248
Allen et al. score: 8
Paired Regions (query5'-query3',transcript3'-transcript5')
    1-3,1331-1329
    5-8,1328-1325
    10-19,1323-1314
    20-20,1312-1312
Unpaired Regions (query5'-query3',transcript3'-transcript5')
    4-4,x-x BULq: Bulge on query side
    9-9,1324-1324   SIL: Symmetric internal loop
    x-x,1313-1313   BULt: Bulge on transcript side
    21-21,1311-1311 UP3: Unpaired region at 3' of query

Degradome data file: /media/owner/newdrive/phasing/degradome/_degradome.20171210/bbduk_trimmed/merged_HV2.fasta_dd.txt
Degardome Category: 4
Degradome p-value: 0.013385336399181
```

I tried to do this for before and after values, then I keep getting errors. Sorry I am new to perl and would really appreciate your help. Here are some of the codes I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;
use Modern::Perl;

my word = "Query:";

my $filename = $ARGV[0];
open(INPUT_FILE, $filename);
while (<<>>) {
chomp;
my ($before, $after) = m/(.+)(?:\t\Q$word\E:\t)(.+)/i;
say "word: $word\tbefore: $before\tafter: $after";
}
```

Comment: @zdim It's fixed.

Comment: Posted, but there may be question about the exact data format (on which the answer relies, and some of which I assumed). Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need straight pieces of data from each section, and both sections and data come clearly demarcated, the only question is of what data structure to use.  Given that you want mere lines with values collected from each section a simple array should be fine.

It is known that the phrases of interest, `Query:` then `Degardome Category: N` then `p-value`, are unique to the context and places shown in the sample.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $file = shift || die "Usage $0 file\n";

open my $fh, '<', $file  or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my (@res, @query, $category, $pvalue);

while (<$fh>) {
    next if not /\S/;

    if (/(.*?)\s+Query:\s+(.*)/) {
        @query = ($1, $2);
        next;
    }   

    if (/^\s*(Degardome Category:\s+[0-9]+)/) {
        $category = $1; 
    }   
    elsif (/^\s*(Degradome p-value:\s+[0-9.]+)/) {
        $pvalue = $1; 
        push @res, [$category, $pvalue, @query];
    }   
}

say "@$_" for @res;
```

The end of a section is detected with the `p-value:` line, at which point we add to the `@res` an arrayref with all needed values captured up to that point.

The regex throughout depends on properties of data seen in the sample.  Please review and adjust if some of my assumptions aren't right.

Details can also be pried from data more precisely, even by simply adding capture groups to the regexes above (and saving those captures into additional data structures).

Comment: Thank you, but why am I getting this error: `perl grab_text_from_cleaveland_output.pl IGR-output.txt            
Modification of non-creatable array value attempted, subscript -1 at grab_text_from_cleaveland_output.pl line 22, <$fh> line 13`

Comment: @MAPK  I just copy-pasted my code from this post, and your sample data and am getting the correct output?  I am adding the output to the answer...

Comment: @MAPK I realize I left out the `Category`, adding ... but it works fine for me.

Comment: @MAPK Got it: There is a `Query:` in the beginning of the file, before any `Degardome Category`.  Then the code matches it and tries to add it to the array ... which doesn't exist yet.  What do you want with that line, before any `Degardome Category` was seen in the file?

Comment: Actually it should grab the this type of values first: `3' UGACGUUUCAGUUCCCAGUAU 5' Query: Seq_3694_200` , and then `Degradome Category` comes after that.

Comment: For my example data, there will be only one output.

Comment: @MAPK Ah. Different than the posted sample data (please be careful with that).  OK, will fix it. To confirm: is there _always_ first `Query`, then `Category` and `p-value`?  And do you still want the output as shown?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @MAPK Also: is there any other way or place where there could be the phrase `Query:` ?  I looked down the file but it's too big to scan whole :).  Plus, other files may be a little different...

Comment: `Query:`, `Degradome Category` and `Degradome p-value:` are unique to make one row in the result.

Comment: @MAPK Done, updated answer.  With the file you showed there are 284 lines of output. Categories alternate between 0 to 4. p-values less than zero except for two that are over 7 and one over 3.

Comment: Thank you so much. I mostly work in R and this was completely new to me. Helped a lot!

Comment: @MAPK Alright :)  Apart from the regex, it's purely procedural and would go very similarly in any language, so it may be useful in that sense too.

Comment: @MAPK I'd suggest to update the data sample, so to start from `Query:` etc. -- for those who may come later.  I can do it, too, if that's not a problem (to extract a handful of lines from the full file you linked).

Comment: Updated! Thanks again!